# GET Request returning 403 Forbidden but works on apitester?

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, okhttp

I am trying to get the responce from the server but it is returinig 403 forbidden but testing api on apitester.com works.

This is the code how i am reqesting the get method :

```
public void getResponse(Context context) throws IOException {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Hmac hmac = new Hmac();
        String auth = hmac.txt;
        String url = "https://api.hotstar.com/h/v1/play?contentId=1000034502";
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .addHeader("hotstarauth",auth)
                .addHeader("referer","https://hotstar.com/movies/2-states/1000034502")
                .addHeader("x-country-code","IN")
                .addHeader("x-platform-code","TABLET")
                .addHeader("x-region-code","undefined")
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error Occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                Log.d("Server Responded: ", response.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

and in response i am getting 403 FORBIDDEN

but using the same config on apitester.com it works !
here is the sharedconig on apitester https://www.apitester.com/shared/checks/dca814bb92fb40af8aecda95cdf2f39c

why i am not getting the response on android ?

Comment: Are you sure you have access to call that API from your android side? Because it can be restricted to be called from their own website and not anyone else.

Comment: @AdibFaramarzi Yes i am sure the api is not restricted. the problem is the api is acceable from WebBrowsers but in android app it is returing the 403 code. you can check youtube-dl for confirmation it is working but don't know how it wokrs in android. as the old link is expired i am editing the main question and posting it hope you see it before it get expired.

Comment: Could you check with another API? something like [mocky.io](https://www.mocky.io/)

Comment: Sorry i couldn't made it

Comment: https://www.apitester.com/shared/checks/dca814bb92fb40af8aecda95cdf2f39c this is the updated link

Comment: and this is how hotstarauth is being created https://onlinegdb.com/HJqygU244 if link expires you can get the updated hotstarauth by compiling this.

Comment: What I mean was, create a mock API (like using mocky.io) and use that API in your request and see If that fails or not.

Comment: @AdibFaramarzi sir didn't found any use of that in this case. i found other apps doing this with WebView i don't know how. But i can't find that still now.